Can we read on books or do we have to read in them?
We don't read on books but in them.
A while ago one of the site's members told me this, and I couldn't help mulling it over and over again as semantics is related to perspective. When I say I am reading on a book, as I read a bidimensional object which is the sheet of paper, I think I read on it, not through it(I guess one can metaphorically speaking read through the pages of a book so "in" does make perfect sense when you see it that way), I suppose one could also get the idea of literally reading upon a book which I find pretty odd and wouldn't think of this possible meaning as the intended meaning on the part of the speaker, but as my sight is focused and aimed at this bidimensional object, do you think that depending on one's perspective this idea could be logical?
When Reading in a book I think of a book as a container, so when you read in it, you sort of dive metaphorically speaking into its content to get the information you need. Do these ideas make sense to you?
For instance, according to the Oxford Collocations Dictionary the prepositions in and on collocate with the noun mind and I wonder why would these two words be suitable in this case, I think it depends on perspective and on the concept of space.

When you say you're "reading on a book", you're nor speaking English. You can see something on the TV, or hear it on the radio, but you can only read it in a book. Labeling them "surface" or "container" metaphoric usages doesn't change the fact that's how Anglophones speak and write.

We read this or that in a book, not 'read in a book' by itself. The question is asking for logic, although language grows by speaking and not by rules.

NEWSPAPER: "I read the news about Joe Biden IN The New York Times, it was ON the front page." It seems contradictory, why isn't the news on the NYT?  We open a newspaper to read what is inside, just as you open a book to read its content or  open a door to get INTO a room.

Reading in a book implies the idea of a book being like a container, and when you read in it, you sort of dive in its content to get the information you need ... not really ... it is because the words are printed inside the book

What is your question? You have answered the title question in the text "We don't read on books but in them."  That's it.  There's nothing more to say.  Whether your "logic" says that "on" would be better or not is irrelevant.  There doesn't appear to be any other question here.

You could read something on a book if it was on the cover. If I heard this then that is what I would assume they meant, unless anything else was obvious from the context.

I also read "in a book" but it doesn't mean I dive into it and read. The same preposition can be used "in the newspaper"

A book isn't a sheet of paper. It's a large number of sheets of paper fastened at one side and placed inside a cover. As a learner, do you know what a book is?

The continuous action is most often described as "reading a book". That is an action performed on the book. It contains information and you are consuming the information.
"Reading in a book" as in "I am reading about Egypt in a travel book" also described the book as a container or collection of information which you access. The same is true for newspapers, articles, journals and other printed media.
Compare to websites where you say "read on" as in "I am reading about English on ell.stackexchange.org".
"Reading on a book" means you are physically standing/sitting/lying on top of a book and also reading something. It is not correct in the sense you are describing.

We also use "at" for websites, due to the "site" metaphor.

The preposition "on X" is used when X is treated like a surface, like a plate sitting on the table. "in X" is used when X is a container, as in a letter in an envelope.
Books are usually viewed as containers, so we read things in books.
However, the book cover and jacket are surfaces, so we can say that we read the author's name on the book cover.
Pages are also surfaces, so you say you read something on page 100 of the book.
